# Three.js - Only renders scene background but no geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I will honestly rip my hair out of my head. I need help seriously. All that I need to do is get something/ anything to render in this very simplistic three.js program. I've wasted so much time, and just want to cry myself to sleep...

I can only see the background color of the scene. I've tried putting in simple cubes, copy pasted geometries, geometries from other projects which work, messing around with ambient and directional lights, moving the camera position around. To save my life, I can't get a single distinct pixel.. No console errors, no errors in vs code, other projects work fine. It's like whatever project I set out to work on that is inspired has to be beaten down again and again, like beating a dead horse, by typically some very stupid errors. This dynamic wall has come to my front door this time, to block me in at the very outset...

The html is fine. As I said, it renders the scene background just fine. It does not render any shaded geometries whatsoever. Running the webapp on node liveserver... browser is fully updated Firefox...

```
var context = null,
    renderer = null,
    loader = null,
    scene = null,
    camera = null;

var redSphere;
var cube;

function onLoad() {

    //CONTEXT
    context = document.getElementById("deep");
    context.style.height = "100vh";
    context.style.width = "100vw";

    //RENDERER
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    context.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    //CAMERA
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, context.offsetWidth/context.offsetHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    //SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color("rgb(20, 0, 20)");

    //LIGHTS
    var sun1 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
    var sun2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
    var sun3 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
    sun1.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    sun2.position.set(-3, 3, 2);
    sun3.position.set(0, -3, 2);
    scene.add(sun1, sun2, sun3);



    //RED OBJECT
    var sphereGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var redSphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: "rgb(255, 0, 0)" });//, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true
    redSphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, redSphereMat);
    redSphere.position.set(0, 5, 0);
    scene.add(redSphere);


    draw();
}

function draw() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    camera.lookAt(redSphere);

    redSphere.rotation.y -= 0.1;

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

lookAt() needs a Vector3 as argument, not a Mesh. Try:

`camera.lookAt(redSphere.position);`

Comment: More specifically a THREE.Vector3 ;) :)